# Is it possible to serialise a comma delimited list of single JSON objects to a collection in Java?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm attempting to serialise a list of single JSON objects, delimited by a comma to a collection of some sort in Java using Jackson.

Am I correct in thinking this is only possible using a custom mapper due to how the JSON is presented?

JSON input:

```
{"_1":"186","_3":"In Stock"},{"_1":"187","_3":"In Stock"},{"_1":"188","_3":"In Stock"},{"_1":"189","_3":"In Stock"}
```

POJO

```java
public class StockInfo {

    private String _1;

    private String _3;


    @JsonProperty("_1")
    public String get_1() {
        return _1;
    }

    @JsonProperty("_1")
    public void set_1(String _1) {
        this._1 = _1;
    }

    @JsonProperty("_3")
    public String get_3() {
        return _3;
    }

    @JsonProperty("_3")
    public void set_3(String _3) {
        this._3 = _3;
    }
}
```

Serialisation

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);

List<StockInfo> stockList = objectMapper.readValue(resultInputStream, new TypeReference<List<StockInfo>>(){});
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Your input string needs to be a JSON array (add `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end).

Comment: @lugiorgi @lugiorgi `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList<com.domain.StockInfo> out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectRecordsInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson won't be able to parse that since it's simply not a valid JSON format, unless for example the JSON objects were in a JSON array:

```json
[{"_1":"186","_3":"In Stock"},{"_1":"187","_3":"In Stock"},{"_1":"188","_3":"In Stock"},{"_1":"189","_3":"In Stock"}]
```

If you have no control over the format you get your data in, you could just wrap the pseudo-JSON string in square brackets, making it a JSON array:

```java
// Wrap the pseudo-JSON string in square brackets, making it a JSON array
String jsonArray = "[" + pseudoJson + "]";

// Parse like you intended
List<StockInfo> stockList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonArray, new TypeReference<>() {});
```

Or you could split the string and then attempt to parse each object individually:

```java
// Split the pseudo-JSON string at commas preceded by a closing curly bracket
String[] jsonObjects = pseudoJson.split("(?<=}),");

// Parse each JSON object to a StockInfo instance and add it to a List
List<StockInfo> stockList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String jsonObject : jsonObjects) {
    StockInfo stockInfo = objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, new TypeReference<>() {});
    stockList.add(stockInfo);
}
```

The closest thing Jackson offers would be `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`, but in your case you'd only get the first element.

Comment: thanks I thought this would be the case, I had thought of wrapping the JSON in brackets so it could be serialised but the result is returned in as an InputStream and I would rather not convert it to String due to the size of the result. I assume this can't be done whilst the result is an InputStream?